# Riced potatoes recipe called steurens or steritz?

Tags: potatoes

Trying to find a recipe for my older neighbors.  they think it's called steurens or steuritz... seems to be riced potatoes made into either dumplings or noodles... can't find anything named that online.... has anyone hear of this?  Many thanks!

Comment: Do you know the ethnicity of the recipe? Or the language the recipe name would be in?

Comment: Hi Nanette. Welcome to Seasoned Advice. It sounds like you're on an interesting hunt. I'm with @Jolenealaska. Some sort of nationality would be helpful. When I hear potato dumpling I think of things like gnocchi, pierogi, or spätzle, the latter bearing a closer resemblance to your words.

Answer (score 5):

It might be the dish called "Sterz", common in Switzerland, Austria, and a little further away in Slovenia and Croatia.

Comment: I think you've nailed it!

Comment: Google translates sterz as mush :) Awesome.